# angular mat-table with dynamic columns and row headers for a data array

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

The table should display the data as defined in displayedColumns. The group column has a rowspan of 2 and the row column displays the [rows.title] which is the row header and displayed for every iteration. The rest of the columns displays the data with regards to the row.title and col If anyone can help out with the table html .

```
//column order
let displayedColumns = ['group','row','0','1','2'];

// tabledata object
let tableData = [{
  salesHist: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  sales: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  forecastHist: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  forecast: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  group: "000",
  recordCount: "1234",
  rows: [{
    key: "forecast",
    title: "Forecast"
  }, {
    key: "sales",
    title: "Sales"
  }, {
    key: "salesHist",
    title: "Sales History"
  }]
}];

//table html
<table
  mat-table
  matSort
  [dataSource]="table"
  multiTemplateDataRows
  class="w-100"
>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let group of table" matColumnDef="group">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      {{ group }}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [attr.rowspan]="4">
      {{ group }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="row">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
      <span *ngFor="let rowTitle of row.rows">{{ rowTitle.title }}</span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let periodCol of monthsPeriod"
    matColumnDef="{{ periodCol.col }}"
  >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      {{ getTitle(periodCol) }}
    </th>
    <td class="sim-row-cell" mat-cell *matCellDef="let rowTitle">
      {{ getValue(rowTitle, periodCol) }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: have  a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596224/6720372

Comment: @SufailKalathil Thanks ! How do I also iterate the rows from the tableData object for the second column which acts as a row header

Answer (score 1):

I thing this can give you some ideia to solve your issue. Take a look
component.html

```
<app-loading *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></lotus-app>

<div *ngIf="(isLoading$ | async) === false">
   <ng-container *ngIf="dataSource.data.length >= 1; else noData">
      <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="col.key">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
               {{cols[i]["display"]}}
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
               <ng-container *ngIf="!col.config; else hasConfig">
                  {{element[col.key]}}
               </ng-container>
               <ng-template #hasConfig>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="col.config.isDate">
                     {{element[col.key] | date:'short'}}
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="col.config.isCurrency">
                     {{element[col.key] | currency}}
                  </ng-container>
               </ng-template>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="keys"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: keys;"></mat-row>                                     
       </mat-table>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #noData>
       <h3>Ops...</h3>
       <p>There is no data...</p>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  cols = [
    { key: 'username', display: 'User Custom displayed name in column' },
    { key: 'salary', display: 'Some coin', config: { isCurrency: true } },
    { key: 'email', display: 'email' },
    { key: 'birthday', display: 'Birthday', config: { isDate: true } }
  ];
...
component logic..
// This is important to map all keys 
get keys() { return this.cols.map(({ key }) => key); }
```

In that way you can add N columns, with a custom name to display
You only need to set the displable name in att `display` and use the `key` att to fetch if the server response.

in the template `*matHeaderRowDef="keys"` will get response from `get keys()`, but will display in tables header the display att value

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="col.key">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          {{cols[i]["display"]}}
```

...

Keep coding \m/